# Locale/Culture problems converting string to decimal

Tags: c#

I have a simple string received via a parameter:

"1.00"

Based on locale of visitor it sometimes converts to:

"1" or "1,00"

The second one is a problem, I always need it to be a period (dots). $,£

I am using:

```
decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(stringPrice, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Why is it still converting to "1,00" decimal if I use en-GB culture? I tried InvariantCulture, and the same thing happens. Why is this happening? It shouldn't matter because it's on the back end, right?

Comment: `Convert.ToDecimal("1.00", new CultureInfo("en-GB")) == 1` returns true. Could you please clarify "it still converting to "1,00" decimal"?

Comment: Are you saying that the string is always received as 1.00 and is then sometimes coverted to 1,00 or 1?  Or are you saying that the string that is sent is sometimes 1,00 and sometimes 1.00?  I.e, is the convert result different or is the original string different?

Comment: A `decimal` is a floating point value, in addition to what @AlexeiLevenkov pointed out `Convert.ToDecimal("1.00", new CultureInfo("en-GB")) == 1.00` will also return true. After the `Convert.ToDecimal` conversion it is no longer a string, and whatever amount of zeros displayed behind the decimal point meaningless. Not until you convert it back to a string, using a given string format, will any of it matter.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion is going fine - internally, you get a decimal representation of 1.00 in your variable (price). Whether you see "1,00" or something else depends on where you are *outputting* the variable. Please look at how you are printing it, to see how it should display.